# How to get a particular point of an detected object with ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

My question is about object detection and get a particular point from it.

For example, if I want to implement this, how would you tackle this?

> You put a white paper in front of your camera and let it detect
>   it. As soon as that paper is detected, some action (like any action such as a node is produced somewhere in the screen) is triggered.

One solution that came through my head is to do some hit test, thinking it would give me a node position of a first detected by hit test. But it seems like it is not working as desired. I want to see a new node being created up above that paper, based on the position of the detected real object.

Is marker based detection is better for achieving this program, or is there any better solution to this?

Comment: Any progress on this?